# C++ DLL Injection get Struct values

Tags: dll, struct, code-injection, rtti

I am trying inject into a dll that sends a void ** for one of the parameters.

The void ** can contain structs that are created in the application.

Is there any way of getting data out of the structs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correcly you want to create a function in a DLL that accepts a void** and then be able to figure out what structs the caller has passed through the void** parameter.

In that case the answer is that no, you cannot do that. The function accepting the void** needs to know what is inside it. There is no such thing as reflection in pure C++ that can handle that situation.